# Testing expression tree method via Moq not using expression logic

Tags: c#, nunit, moq, expression-trees

The problem: running the code outright creates the proper filtering, and my unit test is not filtering at all (returning all records in the mocked repository).

I can't tell if having the expression logic in the test is screwing something up or what, but no matter the criteria I set, the mocked repository is not filtered on ad I can back "all" records.  This works 100% from the service layer calling it, but not in tests.

Edit: sorry for the formatting of the code, I couldn't get it any better.

**Code**:

```
public abstract class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEFModel {

public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

private IDbSet<T> _objectset;
private IDbSet<T> ObjectSet
{
    get { return _objectset ?? (_objectset = UnitOfWork.Context.Set<T>()); }
}

public virtual IQueryable<T> WhereInternal(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return ObjectSet.Where(expression);
} }
```

implementation:

```
public class DoNotSolicitRepo : EFRepository<DoNotSolicit>, IDoNotSolicitRepo {
private readonly RestUnitOfWork worker;

public DoNotSolicitRepo(RestUnitOfWork _worker)
{
    worker = _worker;
}

public IList<DNSContract> SelectWithCriteria(DNS_Search search)
{
    // create the where clause 
    Expression<Func<DoNotSolicit, bool>> whereClause = c => (
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.FirstName) || c.FirstName.StartsWith(search.FirstName)) &&
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.LastName) || c.LastName.StartsWith(search.LastName)) &&
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Address1) || c.Address1.Contains(search.Address1)) &&
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Address2) || c.Address2.Contains(search.Address2)) &&
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.City) || c.City.Contains(search.City)) &&
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.State) || c.State.Equals(search.State)) &&
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Zip5) || c.Zip.Equals(search.Zip5)) &&
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Phone) || c.Phone.Equals(search.Phone)) &&
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Email) || c.Email.Equals(search.Email))
        );

    using (var scope = worker)
    {
        scope.Register(this);
        var resultList = WhereInternal(whereClause).ToList();

        Mapper.CreateMap<DoNotSolicit, DNSContract>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.PartnerCode, opt => opt.Ignore())
           .ForMember(dest => dest.PartnerDescription, opt => opt.Ignore())
           .ForMember(dest => dest.DoNotSolicitReason, opt => opt.Ignore())
           .ForMember(dest => dest.SaveDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
           .ForMember(dest => dest.InsertDT, opt => opt.Ignore());

         var returnObj = Mapper.Map<IList<DoNotSolicit>, IList<DNSContract>>(resultList);

         return returnObj.FriendlySaveDates();
    }
} }
```

**Test**:

base:

```
public abstract class BaseEFUnitFixture<T> where T : BaseEFModel {
protected Mock<EFRepository<T>> mockedEFRepo = new Mock<EFRepository<T>>();

public Mock<EFRepository<T>> MockedEFRepositiory()
{
    var t = new List<T>();

    mockedEFRepo.Setup(x => x.AddInternal(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback((T e) => t.Add(e));
    mockedEFRepo.Setup(x => x.AddInternal(It.IsAny<List<T>>())).Callback((IList<T> le) => t.AddRange(le));
    mockedEFRepo.Setup(x => x.AllInternal()).Returns(t.AsQueryable());
    mockedEFRepo.Setup(x => x.WhereInternal(It.Is<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>(y => y != null))).Returns(t.AsQueryable());

    return mockedEFRepo;
}
```

}

implementation:

```
[TestFixture] public class DNSRepoTest : BaseEFUnitFixture<DoNotSolicit> {
private readonly List<DoNotSolicit> list = new List<DoNotSolicit>();

private class Search
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip5 { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

private Expression<Func<DoNotSolicit, bool>> SearchBuilder(Search search)
{
    //  same as repo logic
    Expression<Func<DoNotSolicit, bool>> whereClause = c => (
       (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.FirstName) || c.FirstName.StartsWith(search.FirstName)) &&
       (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.LastName) || c.LastName.StartsWith(search.LastName)) &&
       (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Address1) || c.Address1.Contains(search.Address1)) &&
       (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Address2) || c.Address2.Contains(search.Address2)) &&
       (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.City) || c.City.Contains(search.City)) &&
       (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.State) || c.State.Equals(search.State)) &&
       (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Zip5) || c.Zip.Equals(search.Zip5)) &&
       (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Phone) || c.Phone.Equals(search.Phone)) &&
       (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Email) || c.Email.Equals(search.Email))
       );

    return whereClause;
}

[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void Init()
{
    list.Add(new DoNotSolicit
                 {
                     DoNotSolicitID = 4,
                     FirstName = "nunit",
                     Origination = "testing"
                 });

    mockedEFRepo = MockedEFRepositiory();
    mockedEFRepo.Object.AddInternal(list);
}

[Test]
public void SelectWithCriteria_FirstNameMatch()
{
    var clause = SearchBuilder(new Search{FirstName = "test"});
    var results = mockedEFRepo.Object.WhereInternal(clause).ToList();

    Assert.IsNotNull(results);
    Assert.IsTrue(results.Count < mockedEFRepo.Object.AllInternal().Count());
    Assert.IsTrue(results.Count > 0);
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong with your approach in general. What you do you mock the class that you test - it is incorrect. You should only mock something external to the class you are testing - because what mocking does is pretty much replacing the functionality with of mocked object with empty stubs. If it's mocked it doesn't work or work as the mock is configured.

I see no reason why you would want to test the mocked class, as in this case what you are testing is not the class functionality/code but the way you configured your mock.

It's quite hard to understand what code do you want your test method to test. I would suggest doing the dependency injection to separate the actual data repository (which could be mocked with specific data/methods) and the class that contains logic (like selecting the first match). Pass mocked repository in the constructor of your logic class and test it asserting the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I haven't used mocks aside from some little things here and there and I get what you are saying.  I wasn't comfortable with mocking the repo, but I wanted it tested and made less sense as I started to look at testing the service layer just now.  I'll just inject the mock into the service tests which makes more sense, what I'm more accustomed to.  Thanks.